# How to load partial using Ajax request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

I want to load partial using Ajax request. I created drop-down list having Ajax request.

```
<select name="search" id="search" onselect="new Ajax.Request('/calendar/find', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get', parameters:'is_delivery_address=' + escape(value) }); return false;">

            <option value="0">A</option>
            <option value="1">B</option>
            <option value="2">C Calendar</option>

           </select>
```

And In the controller:

```
def find
    render :update do |page|

      if ["0"].include?(params[:is_delivery_address])

        page.replace_html :appRightContent, :partial=> 'calendar/trainer_view'
      else
        page.replace_html :appRightContent, :partial=> 'calendar/venue_view'
      end
    end
end
```

When I run this code Ajax request is not working and I got following error.

```
Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead
```

What should I do to work this request? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with your version of prototype and rails javascript helper methods. Use an older version of Prototype. I think a version before 1.6.x should work.

Comment: I changed my prototype version into 1.5.1.2. But still it throws the same error and not working ajax request..